# c++ std::vector: sum in a vector position its previous value

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, sum, std

I need to accomplish a simple task, which seems to be forbidden in c++ language.

I have a simple `std::vector<double> a{1.,2.,3}`and I want to do this simple thing:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.size();i++)
   a[i]=a[i]+0.1; //or a[i]+=0.1;
```

or, likely, with pointers:

```
for (auto it = a.cbegin(); it != a.cend(); ++it)
    *it=*it+0.1;
```

How can I manage to do it without compiling errors? Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see an error in this for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<a.size();i++)
   a[i]=a[i]+0.1;
```

except that the compiler can issue a warning that there is a comparison of a signed integer with an unsigned integer in the condition of the loop.

You could write the loop like

```
for( std::vectpr<double>::size_type i=0; i < a.size(); i++ )
   a[i] = a[i]+0.1;
```

or just like

```
for( size_t i=0; i < a.size(); i++ )
   a[i] = a[i]+0.1;
```

In this for loop

```
for (auto it = myvector.cbegin(); it != myvector.cend(); ++it)
    *it=*it+0.1;
```

you are using `std::vector<double>::const_iterator` that may not be used to change elements of the vector.

You could wrute a range-based for loop like

```
for ( auto &item : myvector ) item += 0.1;
```

provided that `myvector` is not a constant object or a reference to a constant object.

Here is a simple demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 1., 2., 3. };
    
    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    for ( auto &item : v ) item += 0.1;
    
    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 
1.1 2.1 3.1
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "except that the compiler can issue a warning that there is a comparison of signed integer with an unsigned integer in the condition of the loop.". What are the two integers compared?

Comment: @fslack The variable i has the signed integer type int while the expression a.size() has the unsigned integer type std::vector<double>::size_type.

Comment: anyway I don't think it is the problem. If I use the for loop only to print the starting values, it works. I think it has problem with the expression a[i]=a[i]+0.1;

Comment: @fslack It is not a big problem but a bad style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::vector::cbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) returns read-only iterators. Use `begin()` and `end()` instead of `cbegin()` and `cend()`. Also don't forget to declare `myvector`.

```
std::vector<double> myvector = a;

for (auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
    *it=*it+0.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with a range-based for loop

```
for(auto & e: a) e += 0.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach algorithm and lambda expression:

```
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [](double &d){ d += 0.1; });
```

Comment: If you're going to use an algorithm, I'd suggest `std::transform` to make intent more clear.